# DW01A IC in TP4056c Li-ion protection module turns off the output

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, tp4056

I have a strange problem where a TP4056c Li-ion charger/protection module with a TP4056 IC and a DW01A IC is not working: <1 V comes as output.

I have connected the output from the module to a 3.3 V LDO voltage regulator. I have checked that the battery protection IC DW01A has turned off the MOSFETs connected to OD and OC for no apparent reason. If I bypass the battery protection IC DW01A by shorting the battery negative to the common negative, it works perfectly, except the battery protection.

I have checked all components to be correct and there is no short-circuit or high load in the rest of the circuit.

[image]

Comment: Commercial module or DIY circuit?

Comment: CLOSE VOTERS: THE QUESTION IS CLEAR.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is C3, 10 uF. Its inrush current is seen as a temporary short circuit.

The [spec sheet pf the TLV0233](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv702.pdf?ts=1700928037182&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLV702%252Fpart-details%252FTLV70233DBVR) says that you only need 0.1 uF.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar question posted here: [Lithium ion battery protection IC not able to drive MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/382811/lithium-ion-battery-protection-ic-not-able-to-drive-mosfet/397019#397019)

The solution it seems is to use a slightly lower value of C2 (mentioned 100 nF in datasheet but use 80 nF) capacitor across pin 5 and 6 of DW01A. This is really strange. I will test it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Battery protection will not work as the MOSFETs are bypassed, I faced similar problem but if both the bat -ve and ground connected temporarily the issue get fixed . I am also searching for the proper reason