# Is it OK to have two protectors for a single Li-ion battery?

Tags: lithium-ion, protection, tp4056

I have a question regarding a Li-ion charger/protector module. The board I'm using a fairly standard Li-ion charger/protector module.
[image]

This module manages the charge using a TP4056 IC and has a built-in protection circuit using the DW01A IC.

Can I use this module safely to charge a 3.7 V Li-ion battery without internal protection? Most Li-ion batteries have an internal protection circuit (see image).
[image]

But when I use the TP4056 module as described and a battery with internal protection there is a double protection, and this seems to be causing problems. So I want to use a battery without this internal protection.
[image]

I'm assuming this is OK since the protection is present in the system only it is on the charge PCB and not on the battery. But I have done a lot of research and I'm still not a 100% sure so I was hoping someone could help here.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to have two protector boards, one on the Li-ion battery and the other in the charging/protection module.

If necessary, one of the two protectors will turn off. It doesn't matter which because the result is the same: the LI-ion cell will be protected.

Comment: PS: The problem i have seems to be that same that is described in this post. The problem resolves when i test with the protection circuit removed from te battery.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/588753/li-po-protection-circuit-dw01a-turned-off-output?rq=1

Comment: @Stijn Schreutelkamp
  " if there is a proper security circuit on the charge board then could I not just use a battery without protection?" You could use a "cell" without protection. Yes.

Comment: Again thank you very much! i will try to figure out best i can is the protection circuit on the charge board is safe. It seems i need to study more just to be safe.

Comment: "thank you very much". Please upvote and accept my answer.